# Kramers-Kronig relations

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics, physics

I am trying to calculate the change of the refractive index from the change of the absorption coefficient using the [Kramers-Kronig relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations), in *Mathematica*.

```
c = 300000000;

daF[l_] = 500 * 0.28 Exp[-((l - 500)/90)^2];

dnFpoints = Table[
    {
        ln,
        c/Pi NIntegrate[
            daF[li] / ((2 Pi c 10^9 /li)^2 - (2 Pi c 10^9 / ln)^2),
            {li, 800, 200},
            Method -> {"PrincipalValue"},
            Exclusions -> ((2 Pi c 10^9 /li)^2 - (2 Pi c 10^9 / ln)^2) == 0
        ]
    },
    {ln, 300, 600}
];
```

Unfortunately, *Mathematica* displays an error that it does not converge to prescribed accuracy and the output is junk (I would expect a smooth curve with a negative minimum first and then a positive maximum). I am using *version 8*, if it matters.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you intended to use `{li, 200, 800}` instead of `{li, 800, 200}`.

If you do so, then you could visualize the result :

```
ListLinePlot@dnFpoints
```

[image]

Moreover I would rather define  `daF` in the following form :

```
daF[l_]:= 500 * 0.28 Exp[-((l - 500)/90)^2]
c = 3 10^8;
```

**Edit**

Instead of using `Table` of `dnFpoints` I add an alternative method for calculation of `dnF` function.

```
dnF[ln_] := 
  1/( 4c Pi^3 10^18 ) NIntegrate[ daF[li] / ( 1/li^2 - 1/ln^2 ), 
                                  { li, -\[Infinity],  ln, \[Infinity] }, 
                                  Method ->  "PrincipalValue", 
                                  Exclusions ->  Automatic  
                                ] // Quiet
```

In general one should choose appropriate options for `NIntegrate` like `PrecisionGoal` and `MaxRecursion`  however in this case it is quite sufficient to use `Quiet` for evaluating of `dnF` function without outputting any messages generated.

Now we can plot `dnF` function  increasing appropriately a range of the dependent variable, e.g. :

```
Plot[dnF[ln], {ln, 30, 900}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image]

Comment: When you change `ln` for `li` what is `ln` then? I couldn't find a definition for it in the above code and get a non-numerical values error.

Comment: @Matariki mcandril integrates numerically `daF[li]/(f1(li)-f2(ln))` over `li` from `200` to `800`, and then collects results in `Table[{ln, integral(ln)}, {ln, 300, 600}]`. Therefore we can't change variables `li` and `ln`.

Comment: Doh, missed that! Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: ...if the integral he needs actually does go from 800 to 200, then it's a simple matter of changing signs, since $\int_a^b=-\int_b^a$.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I indeed meant 800-200, this comes from the substitution $\omega$->$\lambda$. Of course I knew J. M. comment, but I thought Mathematica does, too ... Is that a bug, or is there more behind the problem?

Comment: @Artes Can you shortly explain why there has to be an error? I think the integral is defined in both ways, as J. M. explained.
Also though I don't have performance issues, I do have issues with the result. I differs by 13 orders of magnitude from the MathLab- and the experimental value. I would expect the extrema in an order of magnitude between 10^-4 and 10^-6. As the schape of curve itself looks fine though, I don't think this is an issue of the numerics - though I cannot find an error in my formula.

Comment: @mcandril If you evaluate e.g. NIntegrate[1/(x - x^2), {x, 2, -1}, Method -> "PrincipalValue", 
 Exclusions -> x - x^2 == 0] the result is the same (modulo -) as in the case {x, -1, 2} unlike for the integrand in your case.   I suppose the problem arises when numerically integrating in a "reverse direction" because of options ` Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> something` for certain kinds of functions.  It is just a kind of issue when working with numerics, and do not think it is a bug since you get messages.

Comment: @mcandril  I don't know why you put `10^9` in the integrand so I think this is the reason of appearing different orders of magnitude.

Comment: @Artes Thanks for the explanation. I work on the optical nm-scale. The Problem was that I forgot thet $\omega\to\lambda$ sustitution for $\text{d}\omega$. Awkward.