# Getting imaginary data from known real data using Kramers-Kronig relations

Tags: programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Kramers-Kronig in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1750/kramers-kronig-in-mathematica)

I am trying to get `epsilon2` (imaginary part) from known `epsilon1` (real part) data with the respective energy values (`w`), using the Kramers-Kronig relations. My code is:

```
{epsilon1, w} = ToExpression@Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Z08GwMa8"];
epsilon2[w_]:= 2/Pi NIntegrate[a epsilon1[a]/(a^2-w^2), {a, 0, 5.5793}, 
    Method-> "PrincipalValue", MaxRecursion->20, Exclusions->{(a^2-w^2)==0}]//Quiet

Plot[epsilon2[w],{w,0,5.57932},AxesOrigin->{0,0},PlotPoints->400]
```

However, by using the code above, I managed only to get a list of irrelevant numbers. The graph of `epsilon1` looks like a sine curve, while that of `epsilon2` looks like an "M" shape.
Any help is greatly appreciated! =)

> <sub>P.S. If pastebin is down, you can get the original data from [revision 1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/13090/1).</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`epsilon1`as you defined it, isn't a function but a list.
You may try something like:

```
{epsilon1, w} = ToExpression@Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Z08GwMa8"];
f = Interpolation[Transpose[{Flatten[w], Flatten[epsilon1]}]]
epsilon2[w_] := epsilon2[w] = 
                2/Pi NIntegrate[a f[a]/(a^2 - w^2), {a, 0, 5.5793}, 
                Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> {(a^2 - w^2) == 0}] //  Quiet
DiscretePlot[epsilon2[w], {w, 0.5, 5.5, .25}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Joined -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hi @belisarius! Thank you =) 2 things: 1) The shape of epsilon2 is there, but it is supposed to be above the x-axis (i.e. flipping the negative region up to the positive region). 2) From my epsilon2 data, the curve should start off from the origin {0,0} rather than from the high values. Is there a problem or something? =)

Comment: @weesiang You may have to check them. That curve is a reasonable approach to your integrand.

Comment: Oh yes!! I miss out a parameter in the equation! Now I got it! Thank you very much @belisarius!

Comment: Hi @belisarius, If I were to integrate from 0 to infinity, how would you alter the syntax?
And also, I would like to ask you if there are alternative commands to DiscretePlot?
=)