# Implementing Kramers Kronig Relation in Mathematica for Reflection Spectrum

Tags: numerics

I'm new to Mathematica and I have to solve this problem but all of my approaches are wrong :(
So, please can anyone help me with this equation?
Here it is:
[image]

Here is my data :
https://pastebin.com/preM342D
The data is in ln(sqrt(R)), w
And here is my code:

```
   {R, w} = ToExpression@Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/preM342D"];
f = Interpolation[Transpose[{Flatten[w], Flatten[R]}]]
theta[w_] := 
 theta[w] = 
  2 w/Pi NIntegrate[ f[a]/(a^2 - w^2), {a, 0, 3.2}, 
     Method -> "PrincipalValue", Exclusions -> {(a^2 - w^2) == 0}] // 
   Quiet
DiscretePlot[theta[w], {w, 0.5, 3.5, .25}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 Joined -> True]
```

P.S. I know that this question was discussed before, but all the answers that were given I can't get to work.
Very appreciate for any help

My output looks like this:
[image]

But it is wrong

Comment: This is closely related [Kramers-Kronig in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1750/kramers-kronig-in-mathematica) or just a duplicate, isn't it?

Comment: What is your output? You include a picture of the equation, but it would be better to include one of your output also. Thank you for providing code with this question! Welcome to mma.SE!

Comment: @CATrevillian , thanks for paying attention! I've added my output in the post.

Comment: A standard way to do the Kramers-Kroning is via the Hilbert transform. There is one [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/341/implementing-discrete-and-continuous-hilbert-transforms) here that provides an extensive answer and many test cases. Please, check it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementing discrete and continuous Hilbert transforms](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/341/implementing-discrete-and-continuous-hilbert-transforms)

Comment: @yarchik Thank you! I've checked it, but it's not the same thing
Or I'm just too dumb to understand how to implement it here

Comment: It is the same thing. You simply have to use the symmetry relations $\Re \chi(-\omega)=\Re\chi(\omega)$ and $\Im \chi(-\omega)=-\Im\chi(\omega)$, where $\chi(\omega)$ is a response function.

Comment: @yarchik , I tried this thing in matlab, but the output looks like the input, I still need help :(

Comment: You need to improve your question in order to attract some attention to it. First, your data is small. You can include it in question. Second, you can plot the original function and describe what kind of output are you expecting as a result. You write, "But it is wrong". What exactly is wrong?

Comment: thanks for your comment, @yarchik. Reflectane in my data doesn't nearly change from 3000 to 7900 cm^-1, so I'm working now only with this piece of data (but I have it from 70 to 7900 cm^-1)
The output should look like a...mountain ? like __/\_ (sorry, my english is too bad to describe it)

Comment: I would say, you need to use all the available data because the integral goes over all frequencies. You talk about cm^-1 but what are the units on the plot?

Comment: okay, I'll try it with the all data.
The units of the x label are cm^-1/1000